# CTE - sum multiple rows with same id (with conditions)

Tags: sql

I want to use SQL to sum multiple rows with same id when wk_days > 10

Sample data :

```
 staff_id    wk_days
--------------------
  A           5
  B           27
  B           4
  C           13
  D           5
```

Output data :

```
 staff_id    wk_days
--------------------
  A           5
  B           31
  C           13
  D           5
```

the above output data is I want, I think I can use CTE to do it. How can it write this SQL Query?

Comment: Tisa if another A present in your data with wk_days value 5 then what will be your output

Answer (score 4):

No CTE needed, that is a simple group by query:

```
select staff_id, sum(wk_days) as wk_days
from the_table
group by staff_id
order by staff_id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MBE21399